# Cannot turn off the touchpad at startup

Tags: scripts, touchpad, startup

I have a startup script that runs from `/etc/rc.local` by:

`sh '/home/sebastian/absolute/path/startup.sh'`

Frtom there I run the turn off script:

`sleep 20 ; sh "/home/sebastian/absolute/path/turn-touchpad-off.sh"`

- script actually runs
- script does not require sudo
- script permissions is `-rwxrwxr-x`
- increasing sleep time won't help
- it doesn't look like the environment turned on touchpad afterwards
- the script works perfectly fine in the shell

The script content:

```
#!/bin/bash
# turns off the Touchpad
device_id="`xinput | grep PS/2 | tr -s " " | cut -f2 | cut -d= -f2`"
status="`xinput list-props $device_id | grep Enabled | awk '{print $4}'`"

echo "Device ID is "$device_id
echo "Enabled "$status

xinput set-prop $device_id "Device Enabled" 0
xdotool mousemove 1920 1080

echo "Touchpad disabled"

exit 0
```

Comment: Not as a solution but as a suggestion, why don't you just execute the scripts as they've `x` permissions?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, to execute the script. Or do you mean to list both in /etc/rc.local or to replace "sh" with "." (source)? I would like to have startup script that points to all other scripts that should be launched on startup.

Comment: @dsstorefile Sorry, my fault. But it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Well, it seems that script has been executed but for some reason couldn't turn off the touchpad.

Comment: What happens if you simply change the script to include the following text only starting from line 3: `synclient TouchpadOff 1`

Comment: The command itself does nothing in my case:

$ synclient TouchpadOff 1
Invalid command: TouchpadOff
Invalid command: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the script from the startup settings:

`XFCE > Settings > Session and Startup > Application Autostart > Add`

Then the script will run after login, so adjusting sleep time will work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your script after your graphical interface is started. So i think you don't get your device-id and status, because xinput is not running when your script executes.

To do debugging and see error messages, execute your script `sh "/home/sebastian/absolute/path/turn-touchpad-off.sh" > /some_dir/logfile` on rc